# Understanding Polymer data-binding and HTML tags

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I'm new to Polymer and while testing data-binding, I discover that I have to encapsulate double-mustache expressions within HTML tags (for example `<span>{{var}}</span>`).

If not, variable is simply not expanded and printed as is.

An exemple (from [Polymer Quick Tour](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/quick-tour.html)), with a line more to show this behaviour. You can also find it [on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wfIygj?p=preview).

```
<dom-module id="name-tag">
  <template>

    <!-- Will print : This is {{owner}}'s name-tag element. -->
    This is {{owner}}'s name-tag element.<br />

    <!-- Will print : This is Daniel's name-tag element. -->
    This is <b>{{owner}}</b>'s name-tag element.
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
Polymer({
  is: "name-tag",
  ready: function() {
    // set this element's owner property
    this.owner = "Daniel";
  }
});
</script>
```

Did I miss something on the documentation, or is this some kind of bug ?

**To the ones that reads this question today**
This behavior seems to have been fixed, in the example on Plunkr, there is no problem anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#binding-to-text-content) :

> The binding annotation must currently span the entire content of the tag.

This means you currently have to wrap your bindings in a tag as you did in this example:

`This is <b>{{owner}}</b>'s name-tag element.`

I expect in the future this will be changed so that you don't have to wrap bindings in a tag.

Comment: Damn, I missed that. Thank you !